# Easy way to access cookies in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, cookies

### To view specific cookies in Chrome, currently I have to:

1. Go to preferences
2. Click <kbd>Under the Hood</kbd> tab
3. Click <kbd>Content Settings...</kbd> button
4. Click <kbd>Cookies</kbd> tab (if it's not already active)
5. Click <kbd>Show cookies and other site data...</kbd> button

If I want to narrow this down to a specific domain, I have to type it in, too.

[image: Chrome Chores]

---

### Compare this to Firefox:

1. View Page Info
2. Click <kbd>Security</kbd> tab
3. Click <kbd>View Cookies</kbd>

The domain for the page I'm currently on is already used as a filter, too.

### My question:

Is there an easier way in Chrome? I've done some searching for an extension but have come up with nothing.

Comment: It's just 2 more clicks, is it really that bad?

Comment: @Daisetsu, don't add comments/answers unless they are worthwhile contributions.

Comment: It wasn't an answer so I posted a comment.  Sorry if I wasted your time.  It looks like you found your answer though anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can view cookies related to current website by right-click -> Inspect Element -> Storage -> Cookies.

Comment: Does not work with current version of Chrome. See @Andrews answer.

Answer (score 9):

Chrome has changed things a little with their developer tools.  The proper procedure for Chrome 11 is:

1. Right click --> `Inspect Element`.
2. Click the `Resources` tab.
3. In the left pane, scroll down and click `Cookies`.
4. You may have to expand `Cookies` (click the little arrow next to it), and click the domain of the site you are currently on to see its cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Quicker, use this chrome extension:
[Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can bookmark **`chrome://settings/cookies`** to go right to the cookies window. You still have to use the search box or scroll if you just want just cookies for the current page.

As Matthieu and Tapkin said, there's an extension. Actually, there are [lots of extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/cookies?hl=en) for this now. Pick one with very good ratings whose publisher looks legit, if you feel trusting.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the best choice is to use external cookie viewers. Such as **ChromeCookiesView** or **CookieSpy**. They both allow view/delete cookies of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As of Chrome 105 / 2022-09-20 (or probably earlier), the procedure has changed again. You now bring up the DevTools window or pane (Ctrl+Shift+I or "Inspect" from the right-click context menu), choose the "Application" tab, and in the "Storage" section at the left-hand side will be a "Cookies" subsection with a list of sites under it:

[image: DevTools / Application / Cookies]

There is also a very nice ["Cookies in use" dialogue box](https://superuser.com/q/1743322/26274) that lists both allowed and blocked cookies and allows you easily to add domains to the allow and block lists. However, as noted in that question, this appears to be accessible only when you're blocking (some?) cookies from that site.