# View cookies : Keyboard shortcut? Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, cookies

While developing a web app, I need to check what cookies the site sent to browser (Chrome), so "Customize > Options > Under the hood > Content Settings > Cookies > Show cookies and other site data" is too many clicks.

I haven't found a keyboard shortcut to get to that page. If there's none, do you know of an extension that would solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty much the same as previous Super User question: [Easy way to access cookies in Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/150730/easy-way-to-access-cookies-in-chrome)

Comment: Not exactly, as I'm looking for a mouse-free, keyboard shortcut to access the list of cookies.

Answer (score 8):

Just came up with a good close enough solution while looking for a keyboard shortcut for cookies myself.

Right click on address bar `edit search engines..`, under `other search engines` you can add urls and keywords. once you add something here, later when you type in the keyword in address bar of tab it will take you to the URL you enter in the `edit search engine`.

I use it as a keyboard shortcut to get to favourite websites. Now in the "edit search engine" add url `chrome://settings/siteData` and any keyword you want , ex: "ck". once you enter that go to a new tab and type "ck" in address bar it will take you to cookie directly. In that page, <kbd>tab</kbd> x3 will let you highlight "remove all" and then hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm. Then <kbd>tab</kbd> x3 again to highlight "clear all" and <kbd>enter</kbd> to confirm.

Comment: Many thanks @ravi, jsejcksn (and OverTheRainbow.) This is such a useful tip. I often delete individual cookies & getting to "All cookies and site data" was a super annoying process. I still don't get what good those Other search engines are, but I'm sure I'll find additional uses for this shortcut functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Closest I've gotten so far is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) to open Inspector/Console without needing to inspect an element and then <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> a couple times to get to Resources, but then I still have to click Cookies.

Another option <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (to open Console), then type `document.cookie`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and get a string dump of the current domain's cookies. Next time you need it, just hit <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> once Console has focus to recall previous command and the <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Don't the developer tools in Chrome (by default) allow you to see cookies, XML HTTP Requests, POST's, etc? Right-click anywhere on a web page and click "Inspect Element"

Once you've enabled resource tracking, the `Storage` tab lets you check out cookies

Comment: Yes, the [Developer Tools](http://www.chromium.org/devtools/google-chrome-developer-tools-tutorial) Storage page will show cookies. You can get to the Developer Tools with Ctrl+Shift+`I`; right click, Inspect element; or Page menu, Developer, Developer tools. (You only need to enable Resource Tracking to use the Resources page. The Storage page always works.)

Comment: Thanks but those require using the mouse. I was looking for a faster way. It looks like Chrome doesn't support this, and no extension is available.

Answer (score 0):

Consider use of external applications for viewing cookies of Google Chrome. My favorite apps are [CookieSpy](http://www.cookiespy.com) and [ChromeCookiesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html). CookieSpy shows cookies for many browsers while ChromeCookiesView  can do more with cookies.

Answer (score -2):

I have used AutoHotKey for automating things like this and also reloading Chrome Extensions as I am developing them.